# Dupehammer incorrect credit

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer

I just closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34213818/157247) with my dupehammer. It now says *"marked as duplicate by T.J. Crowder"*. One problem:

**I'm not the one who did the work finding the original.**

When I voted to close, there was a comment pointing to the original, and a previous close vote recorded. *That* person did the work, not me. I just came along, looked at the question, and at the linked original, and said "yup."

I realize there's no rep involved (there should be, for whoever that person was who did the work, if we could ever find a way to award it that wasn't hugely susceptible to fraud). But could we please at least give credit where credit is due, and list the people who do the work?

Edit: Shog9 says it's by design that it works this way. Removing [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) and adding [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: I'm guessing the original was a flag from a user with not enough rep to vote? otherwise they would have shown up in the list right next to you, assuming they cast a vote at all.

Comment: @Shog9: Surely it's not "by design" that we ignore the contribution of a user **when the system was aware of that contribution**.

Comment: It's very much by design - this is how it works for all close flags. Whether or not the design is correct may be debatable.

Comment: @Shog9: So, let's take the spirit rather than the letter and remove `status-bydesign` and `bug` and add `feature-request`. We don't need lawyering on these, do we? Or do I need to go through the rigmarole of posting it separately? Because that's useful?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder SE doesn't give credit to flag-to-close at all in any circumstance.  Does your proposal mean credit should always given, or just when the dupe hammer is used?  If you mean always, do you mean for just dupes, or for all close flags?  Would you suggest annotating flags from votes differently, or show them all the same?

Comment: Maybe we shouldn't expose low-rep flaggers to the kind of abuse that tends to follow when their name is so clearly visible in the close message.  That will be a very quick end to their desire to participate in moderating.  Not that it is great idea to expose gold badgers to it either but it is okay because they don't complain about it.

Comment: I *saw you* steal that closure. The fact that you're attempting to cover this up is **proof of your crime**.

Comment: @Will: :-) ....

Comment: Sticking on the dupehammer use only with X the **first** "flager" and Y the "dupehammerer": "marked as duplicate by Y, validating X duplicate proposal" sounds a little change to actual message and not a big overhead according to what I understand already exists when the post is closed.

Answer (score 11):

The comment was added by someone who flagged the post. Flags do not count as votes toward closure; they are purely informational. However, your vote marked the flag as helpful.

Comment: But when I went to close it, it clearly showed a previous close-vote (`[1]`) and pre-populated the reason. How did it do that if not via a close vote? That said, I really don't care whether they were able to close-vote or not. If they did the work, and the system is aware of it, as it clearly was, we should give them the credit.

Comment: Yeah, it's worked this way for years. I'm not sure how we'd alter this without making it confusing, but go ahead and post a feature request if you can think of a way...

Comment: Surely the feature request (since you don't think it's a bug, whatever) was clear: List the person who found the original. No one's going to be confused. ([This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269073/dont-say-i-marked-something-as-a-duplicate-when-i-didnt) is much more confusing.)

Comment: Not trying to be obtuse about this, but you're proposing we reveal who flags in certain situations - that's a pretty significant change. For dups, it'd be less shocking; there's already the comment, after all... Still, lotta rough edges there, worth thinking through outside this one scenario.

Comment: @Shog9 Another scenario: user flags VLQ, six reviewers recommend deletion (not a _vote_ to delete, which is a high-rep privilege).  The reviewers are publicly named in the completed review, but the flagger is not identified, even though the flag basically means "I recommend deleting this".

Comment: Something to consider, @Jeff (and TJ): for flags that aren't binding (close, VLQ, NAA) there's no real limit on how many can exist on a post when action is finally taken. So for instance, it's not unusual to have 2-3 people with VLQ flags on an answer when it's deleted, or a couple of dup-flags on a question when it's closed. There *could* be hundreds though; nothing prevents it, it's just unlikely.

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, there's definitely a UI problem to be solved here.  But I think visible rewards for (successful) moderation actions will get newer users in the habit of moderating, a habit I hope will continue until they have the rep for moderation votes.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: visible "rewards" could also discourage new users who may be less-than-confident in their moderation skills and who prefer to practice the art in a less-intimidating environment (i.e. as a private exchange with ♦ users, where the final decision is deferred to them).

Answer (score 3):

"Credit" and close reasons are very blunt.

Suppose someone voted "unclear what you are asking" before you dropped the dupehammer. The site will not say that the first close voter also voted to close as duplicate.

Similarly, if you cast a close vote for reason "unclear what you are asking", and the majority picked a different close reason, the site will now state that *you* also picked that other close reason too.

Comment: *"The site will not say that the first close voter also voted to close as duplicate."* It [does in at least some cases](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269073/dont-say-i-marked-something-as-a-duplicate-when-i-didnt). Which is a bug. I'm obviously not suggesting more bugs. I'm suggesting that someone who did the work of identifying the earlier question be recognized for it. If they flagged for some other reason, obviously don't list them. The system does know why they flagged, it shows that information when I'm using the hammer.

Comment: _"The site will not say"_ -- as T.J. says, this does in fact happen. In fact, it's the norm. I'm wondering if your use of the word "not" here was in fact just accidental. The close banner generally lumps everyone into the same basket as the majority vote reason. I've seen occasionally "other close reasons" displayed, but this is the uncommon case in my experience (I assume it's related to how close the vote was).

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Multiple reasons are only shown if they were all off-topic reasons. For example, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51875/live-as-a-noun. 4/1 splits [exist](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148971/which-type-of-usb-socket-is-this), but are rare, and occasionally you get [2/2 splits](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/32533/cs-subjects-that-an-undergraduate-must-know) or even weirder ones.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: thanks...I'd always wondered what specifically affected that, but never bothered to look into it. Now I know. :)

Answer (score -3):

[Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312138) has addressed the technical merit of your concern, explaining what actually *happens*. But what of the request for a different behavior?

The Stack Overflow model is an exercise in balancing egotism with altruism. IMHO, adding the feature you're requesting would be a shift in the wrong direction.

In general, where users are granted "credit" for their actions, it's done in a way that improves the site overall. Reputation points don't just reward users, they also help serve as a (very rough) indicator of that user's trustworthiness and competence. This provides an important signal to other users to help evaluate posts and (especially, since they offer a much more constrained voting paradigm) comments. It also allows users to take site-improving actions.

But reputation points aren't awarded for closing duplicates. And as Shog9 has pointed out, a flag offered by a user *will* be automatically accepted as "helpful", even if that user did not vote to close or gain any specific credit for closing the question. So as far as the site metrics go, the user has gotten every bit of recognition that the site has to offer them.

So what's left? Public recognition? Even if we assume that every user does in fact want their flag activity revealed (which is what you're talking about here…in and of itself, that's a potentially troubling change in SO philosophy), doing so seems little more to me than ego-stroking. I think it would set a bad precedent for the philosophical stance of the site to suggest that rewarding ego is in any way a primary goal.

I admit that doing so is an inevitable result of any system that rewards users in any way. I'm not saying we should *avoid* things that boost ego. Just that we should make sure that a feature on the site has some *other* benefit beyond that.

The best content on the site comes not from those seeking peer approval, reputation points, or other ego-driven behaviors. Rather, it's from the people who want to *help* and for whom "credit" is at most a secondary concern. For those people, reputation and other "rewards" come naturally anyway, and the site is better for their more outwardly-focused motivations.

Comment: "But reputation points aren't awarded for closing duplicates." Yet. That's more because a system for doing so without allowing abuse hasn't yet been hashed out than because SE is actually opposed to it in principle.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: if and when such a system presents itself, I have no doubt it will remain completely irrelevant to this discussion, as it is now. Either such a system will include flags (in which case, the person who found the dupe in this example will get their just reward) or it will not (in which case the person who found the dupe but did not vote to close as dupe is not due any reward). Either way, that the person is not mentioned in the comments or close banner is not relevant.